# Google Sheets QUERY + SUBSTITUTE to convert dot to coma

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, number-formatting, substitution, google-query-language

Here is my Google Sheets :

[My datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQwGS.png)

I would like to import "QUERY" column M,N,O,P,Q,R into another tab (same sheet) but convert dot "." to coma "," from column Q and R.

I don't know if SUBSTITUTE is the best way and also don't know how to use this inside a QUERY formula.

This formula don't work :
=QUERY({Hoopzi_FlatFileAllOrdersReportbyLastUpdate!M2:Q;SUBSTITUTE(Hoopzi_FlatFileAllOrdersReportbyLastUpdate!Q2:R;".";","))}; "SELECT *")

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX({Hoopzi_FlatFileAllOrdersReportbyLastUpdate!M2:P\
 SUBSTITUTE(Hoopzi_FlatFileAllOrdersReportbyLastUpdate!Q2:R; "."; ",")*1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query({Hoopzi_FlatFileAllOrdersReportbyLastUpdate!M2:P\arrayformula(1*substitute(Hoopzi_FlatFileAllOrdersReportbyLastUpdate!Q2:R;".";","))};"select *")
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your help :)